# TCP Listener for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, tcplistener

I have a C# website, which needs to accept TCP input from GPS Devices,

How can I Design a class inside asp.net website which accept TCP input(TCP Listener inside C# website)?

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the GPS data ? Is it a web-service or something else .

IF it is WCF web-service you can easily consume WCF service . All you need to do is add Reference in your VS project .

If it is REST web-service you can consume by capturing the Data Provided by webpage . See into WebClient Class .

If it is not a web-service you will have to create a Socket Listener in .NET

Use either Socket.Listen Method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen(v=vs.110).aspx

 Or 
TCP Listener 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: getting the data from a gps Device which send in the form of strings

Comment: if u are getting at a particular IP .. you can use Sockets .. Sockets can be used for any type of communication ..